# How to get data from access database where date is selected from a date/time picker?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

The database I'm accessing has the columns : (ID, OrderID, Sandwich, Price, and OrderDate).
The OrderDate column format is date and time.
Here's my code:

```
mycon.ConnectionString = consl
    mycon.Open()
    Try
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [HestiaSales] WHERE [Sandwich] = '" & lbldr.Text & "' AND [OrderDate] = #" & orddt.Text & "#"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, mycon)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            qty = dr.Item(0)
        End While
        cmd.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    mycon.Close()
```

I've tried using `orddt.value` as well but it didn't work, my code was working fine before I added the date lines.
Now every time I run my code it says "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".
Any Ideas?
EDIT: I've up date my syntax to include "#" and I no longer get the previous error, however now I always get a 0 as query result, despite having the correct time picked either from a textbox or a 'datetimepicker' the date is "27/03/2017 16:00:

Comment: Dates are not text.  If the DB Column is a Date type and you pass a date as a date (properly using Parameters - not gluing bits of string together for the SQL), it should work.

Comment: Or if you're using it as a literal date in your SQL, use the # instead of ' to surround the date string.

Comment: @geeFlo I've used your suggestion but now the value displayed is always 0 even though I have the correct date chosen. I have tried a date string with time and the string from the date time picker both didn't work

Comment: I've never used the .text that you seem to be tacking on to your control name.   Why not just use the 'orddt'?

Comment: @geeFlo I've tried that it's still giving me a 0 I'm using 'orddt.value.toshortdatestring' or 'orddt.value.toshortdatestring' and even 'orddt.value' all giving me the same result

Comment: What type of controls are lbldr and orddt.   Are they coming from a form?  Are they comboboxes?  If they're just plain controls then just use `"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [HestiaSales] WHERE [Sandwich] = '" & me!lbldr & "' AND [OrderDate] = #" & me!orddt & "#"`

Comment: @geeFlo lbldr is a label I use to store the sandwich name before sending it to the database for reading and orddt is a date time picker on my form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139277/discussion-between-daniel-darko-and-geeflo).

Comment: The main reason for the problem you are facing is that the date on the `DateTimePicker` inludes the time therefore you will only get the results that match that specific time and nothing else. To fix it change the `WHERE` clause parameter to `format(orddt.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy")` or `format(orddt.Text,"MM/dd/yyyy")` should work either way

Answer (score 0):

declare mydate as Date
then assign value 
mydate= ordt

then try this

```
Try
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [HestiaSales] WHERE [Sandwich] = '" & lbldr.Text & "' AND [OrderDate] = #" & mydate & "#"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, mycon)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            qty = dr.Item(0)
        End While
        cmd.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    mycon.Close()
```